# Convert exported image data

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinary, sql-import-wizard

SQL server management studio does not allow to export image data type so image data type column was exported using the following query:

```
 SELECT 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),ImageDataTypeColumn),2) AS
ImageDataTypeColumn
```

I have the exported data as CSV file, how can I convert it back to the image data type and import it back to the table?

Comment: By reversing the conversions? `SELECT CONVERT(IMAGE, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), MyExportedTextData, 2))`.

Comment: seems to be working - thanks :)